# How to solve No qualifying bean of type 'com.luv2code.springdemo.service.CategoriesService'?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am trying to create a rest api for a categories table. It worked fine when i did it for the customer table. i did everything exactly like i did before but i keep getting this error.

No qualifying bean of type 'com.luv2code.springdemo.service.CategoriesService'

I am using all java configuration for this spring project.

I've tried bunch of answer from the old similar type of question but nothing seems to help

my config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.luv2code.springdemo")
@PropertySource({"classpath:persistence-mysql.properties"})
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    // define a bean for ViewResolver

    @Bean
    public DataSource myDataSource() {

        // create connection pool
        ComboPooledDataSource myDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        // set the jdbc driver
        try {
            myDataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");       
        }
        catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }

        // for sanity's sake, let's log url and user ... just to make sure we are reading the data
        logger.info("jdbc.url=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        logger.info("jdbc.user=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));

        // set database connection props
        myDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        myDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        myDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

        // set connection pool props
        myDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMinPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));     
        myDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));

        return myDataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        // set hibernate properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));

        return props;               
    }


    // need a helper method 
    // read environment property and convert to int

    private int getIntProperty(String propName) {

        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);

        // now convert to int
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);

        return intPropVal;
    }   

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){

        // create session factorys
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        // set the properties
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(myDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("hibernate.packagesToScan"));
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        // setup transaction manager based on session factory
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }   

}
```

here is my Rest controller code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CategoriesRestController {

    // injecting service through Auto wired

    //@Lazy   // use this if auto wired gives you issue
    @Autowired
    private CategoriesService service;

    // to send the list of categories on request
    @GetMapping("/categories")
    public List<Categories> getCategories(){

        return service.getCategories();
    }

    // to GET only one category
    @GetMapping("/categories/{categoryID}")
    public Categories getCategory(@PathVariable int categoryID) {

        Categories categories = service.getCategory(categoryID);


        if(categories == null) {
            throw new CustomerNotFoundException("Category id not found- "+ categoryID);
        }else {
        return categories;
        }

    }


    @PostMapping("/categories")
    public Categories addCategories(@RequestBody Categories categories) {

        // just to make things clear... always set id to 0 when inserting new object
        // so that it will be created instead of update
        categories.setId(0);
        service.saveCategories(categories);

        return categories;
        }
}
```

as i've said it says failed to create No qualifying bean of type 'com.luv2code.springdemo.service.CategoriesService' avialabe

Comment: Can you show us the config classes?

Comment: @PauTrepat i've added config file

Comment: you probably did not annotate that class by "@Service"or "@Component" so Spring cannot find it

Comment: Could be that CategoriesService is not annotated as \@Service or \@Component in the package ur are scanning?

Comment: @mangusta did it still same issue

Comment: @PauTrepat i have done it still same

Comment: try changing this "@ComponentScan("com.luv2code.springdemo")" annotation into "@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.luv2code.springdemo")" - it seems that Spring does not go any further down the subfolders so it is unable to detect the service class

Comment: Can you try it to create a \@Bean of CategoriesService instancing it manually? It´s to see that this is correctly added to IoC at least if you do it by urself

Answer (score -1):

The annotation of your config class will be processed, if your configuration class and your main class are in the same directory. If you have it in two separate packages, you have to move the `@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.luv2code.springdemo")` to top your main class.

Your need to add @Component or @Service at the top of your categoryService too.